# Render multiple variables with express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm pretty new to express! I didn't find the solution here as my console.log perfectly prints out the "user". However, when I display final page the user-data won't show up. It's just empty. Only the concert-data becomes visible on the page. Now I wonder if what I did is even "allowed".

Any Ideas on why the user data does not show up on the rendered page?

```
app.get("/concerts/:id", function(req, res){
Concert.findById(req.params.id, function(err, concert){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        User.find({username: "tyrel"}, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(user);
                res.render("concert", {user: user, concert: concert});
            }
        })
    }
});
```

});

Comment: It is impossible to tell what the specific issue is without knowing what the "concert" template is. But a guess would be a formatting or name-spacing issue with "user".

Comment: can you edit in the template file for "concert"?

Comment: Thanks, I can't edit, but here's a link to the template that's used for rendering:  [codepen](https://codepen.io/kemane/pen/PRLKxJ)

Answer (score 0):

The find() function calls the users as an array, so I had to define an index in my ejs file. `<%=user[0].avatar%>`